# T-SQL: Values are grouped by month, if there is no value for a month the month should also appear and display "NULL"

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

i have a SQL that displays turnover, stock and other values for stores grouped by month. Logically, if there is no value for a month, the month **doesn't appear**. The target is that the empty month should **appear** and display "NULL" for the values. The empty months should range from the @FROM to the @TO parameter (201807 to 201907) in this case.

Before:

```
+-------+--------+----------+----------+-------+
| Store | Month  | Incoming | Turnover | Stock |
+-------+--------+----------+----------+-------+
|   123 | 201810 |        5 |        4 |     1 |
|   123 | 201811 |        0 |        1 |     0 |
|   123 | 201901 |       25 |        5 |    20 |
|   123 | 201902 |        5 |       10 |    15 |
|   123 | 201903 |        8 |        9 |    14 |
|   123 | 201904 |        5 |        4 |    15 |
|   123 | 201905 |       10 |        5 |    20 |
+-------+--------+----------+----------+-------+
```

After:

```
+-------+--------+----------+----------+-------+
| Store | Month  | Incoming | Turnover | Stock |
+-------+--------+----------+----------+-------+
|   123 | 201807 | NULL     | NULL     | NULL  |
|   123 | 201808 | NULL     | NULL     | NULL  |
|   123 | 201809 | NULL     | NULL     | NULL  |
|   123 | 201810 | 5        | 4        | 1     |
|   123 | 201811 | 0        | 1        | 0     |
|   123 | 201812 | NULL     | NULL     | NULL  |
|   123 | 201901 | 25       | 5        | 20    |
|   123 | 201902 | 5        | 10       | 15    |
|   123 | 201903 | 8        | 9        | 14    |
|   123 | 201904 | 5        | 4        | 15    |
|   123 | 201905 | 10       | 5        | 20    |
|   123 | 201906 | NULL     | NULL     | NULL  |
|   123 | 201907 | NULL     | NULL     | NULL  |
+-------+--------+----------+----------+-------+
```

Code Example: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=d81cbe65ab661f075a4ff067f607771b)

I have absolutely no idea how to solve this and will thank you in advance for your help! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to use *cte recursive* make a calendar table, then do outer-join

```
;WITH CTE AS (
   SELECT CAST(CAST(@FROM AS VARCHAR(10)) + '01' AS DATE) fromDt,
          CAST(CAST(@TO AS VARCHAR(10)) + '01' AS DATE)  toDt,
          Store
   FROM (SELECT DISTINCT Store FROM @Test) t1
   UNION ALL
   SELECT DATEADD(MONTH,1,fromDt),toDt,Store
   FROM CTE
   WHERE DATEADD(MONTH,1,fromDt) <= toDt
)
SELECT FORMAT(fromDt,'yyyyMM') Month,
       c.Store,
       t.Incoming,
       t.Turnover,
       t.Stock
FROM CTE c
LEFT JOIN @Test t on 
  c.fromDt = CAST(CAST(t.Month AS VARCHAR(10)) + '01' AS DATE) 
and 
  c.Store = t.Store
```

[sqlfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=f0be0980c76e3fe12de17779aa4ea20e)